# How to get whole array in .map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I'm completely new to React/JSX and its syntax.

```
export const productList = [
    
    {
    id: 'ckes849yz000101md82djen90',
    producer: 'Producent A',
    title: 'Gulerødder',
    type: 'Vaskede',
    image: 'https://raahandel.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/DSC07878.jpg',
    category: 'Frugt & Grønt',
    organic: true,
    cold: false,
    unit: 'kg',
    unitSize: 1,
    bulkUnit: 'Kasse',
    bulkSize: 10,
    price: 8.75,
    quantity: 100,

    descriptions: [{
        productDescription: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        goodBecause: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
    }],

}]
```

i have 5 of these objects in 1 array that i wanna get through .map() in my App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Produkt liste</h1>
        {
          productList.map((product) =>
            <div>
              {product.id}
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

I only know how to get a single value out so far..

thank you.

Comment: That looks fine (except for the lack of `key`, but that won't stop anything working and your ids should work fine as keys). If you have 5 objects in the array you will get 5 divs.

Comment: Thank you, Robin.

But how to I write all 5 objects out with their values?

Comment: Just the way you call `product.id ` same value call every other value

Comment: *"How to write all 5 objects with their values"*: depends on the expected output format. You can of course dump the whole object in JSON format with `JSON.stringify(product)`. Or otherwise iterate the object entries (using `Object.entries(product).map ....`)

Comment: Your code looks to be working as-is https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-mclean-hbtkn. I would check that your list really contains 5 items. If what you're asking is how to get more than the `id` from that object, you just access it with dot notation (ex. `product.title`).

Comment: Daniel - thank you, but I was wondering if there was a way to get both id and producer out in same output.

So calling the <div> </div> and get an object out each output.  So it says both id and producer and not only id.

Comment: Of course it is - just put `{product.producer}` in there as well. How to format the HTML so that the information displays in the way you want is entirely up to you. (And you can of course use CSS as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Replying to the question you just asked Daniel if i understand what your asking correctly you can just do {product.id} {product.producer}